# prevent target element from scrolling to top under some condition

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to disable target from being scrolled to top if the if condition inside handleScroll function is true. So in other words If the condition is true. the user should not be able to scroll to top of the target element anymore and to be able to scroll to bottom of the element.

Also i don't want overflow hidden workarounds if possible.

```
target.addEventListener('scroll', e => this.handleScroll(e, sectionRect, offset, target));

handleScroll(event, sectionRect, offset, target) {
                if ((sectionRect.top - offset) < target.scrollTop)
                    console.log('dont scroll', event);
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible you can see more about  [scroll event here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) and also i recomend see this part:

> "Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler
>   shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM
>   modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using
>   requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent, as follows:"

and this part:

> "In iOS UIWebViews, scroll events are not fired while scrolling is
>   taking place; they are only fired after the scrolling has completed.
>   See Bootstrap issue #16202. Safari and WKWebViews are not affected by
>   this bug."

Maybe creating a custom scroll can be the answer for you.

Comment: i guess yea. seems ill skip this feature :) thanks for asnwer